# Vanishing of an integral.

Tags: complex-analysis

We know $\varphi$ to belong to $\mathcal{C}^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is a region in $\mathbb{C}$. In the proof of a particular statement about subharmonic functions, the following integral is considered:
$$ \int^{2 \pi}_0 \left( \partial^{2}_r + \frac{\partial_r}{r} + \frac{\partial^2_{\theta}}{r^2} \right) \varphi(z_0+r e^{i \theta} ) d\theta. $$ 
In the text it is remarked that: 
$$ \int^{2 \pi}_0  \frac{\partial^2_{\theta}}{r^2} \varphi(z_0+r e^{i \theta} ) d\theta $$ 
vanishes, without further explanation. I assume it's because of $\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{i \theta} d\theta$ vanishes but then I don't see why only this term should vanish and not the other two as well. 
Any clarification is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the integral of a derivative.

$$\frac{\partial^2_\theta}{r^2} \varphi(z_0 + re^{i\theta}) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\varphi(z_0+re^{i\theta})\right).$$

The $\frac{1}{r^2}$ is independent of $\theta$, and since $\theta \mapsto \varphi(z_0+re^{i\theta})$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, so are its derivatives, whence

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\varphi(z_0+re^{i\theta})\right)\,d\theta = \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\varphi(z_0+re^{i\theta})\right]_0^{2\pi} = 0.$$